# How can I disable logins in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server

Can anybody please, let me know that how can we disable a login in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Do you need to completely disable an account, but keep it around?  Do you need to restrict it from just certain databases, but still be able to access other databases on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on exactly what you're after. But the simple SQL to disable a user is:

```
ALTER LOGIN [MyUser] DISABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2000, you can use [sp_denylogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933273(SQL.80).aspx) to deny NT logins/groups access. You can only drop SQL logins.

SQL Server 2005 +, things changed.